# Unity apple sign in and firebase auth

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to sign in with Apple, and I am receiving an error when attempting to pass Apple credentials to Firebase. The full error text is:

> Failed to sign in with Firebase using Apple credentials: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to parse the ID Token.)

So, I'm unable to parse the ID token. Below, you can see the code where I sign in with Apple and try to match the results with Firebase:

```
private void SignInWithApple()
{
    var rawNonce = GenerateRandomString(32);
    nonce1 = GenerateSHA256NonceFromRawNonce(rawNonce);

    var loginArgs = new AppleAuthLoginArgs(LoginOptions.IncludeEmail | LoginOptions.IncludeFullName , nonce1 );
    Debug.Log("Apple login is being initiated.");

    this._appleAuthManager.LoginWithAppleId(
        loginArgs,
        async credential =>
        {   
            Debug.Log("Credential is being obtained.");
            if (credential is IAppleIDCredential appleIdCredential)
            {
                var authorizationCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(appleIdCredential.AuthorizationCode);
                PlayerPrefs.SetString(AppleUserIdKey, appleIdCredential.User);

                var identityToken = System.Convert.ToBase64String(appleIdCredential.IdentityToken);

                Debug.Log($"Apple login information is being transferred to Firebase credential. identityToken: {identityToken}");

                var appleCredential = OAuthProvider.GetCredential("apple.com", identityToken, nonce1, null);
                
                Debug.Log($"Apple login information has been transferred to Firebase credential. {appleCredential}");
                try
                {
                    var firebaseUser = await auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(appleCredential);
                    AddStatusText($"Firebase user info: Email = {firebaseUser.Email}, Id = {firebaseUser.UserId}, Name = {firebaseUser.DisplayName}");
                    Debug.Log("Firebase user info: Email = " + firebaseUser.Email + ", Id = " + firebaseUser.UserId + ", Name = " + firebaseUser.DisplayName);
                    Debug.Log($"Apple login information has been transferred to Firebase credential.");
                    StartCoroutine(InitializeNewUserData(firebaseUser.Email, firebaseUser.DisplayName, "AppleLogin"));
                    StartCoroutine(InitializeFirebaseCoroutine());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Failed to sign in with Firebase using Apple credentials: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        },
        error =>
        {
            var authorizationErrorCode = error.GetAuthorizationErrorCode();
            Debug.LogWarning("Sign in with Apple failed. Error: " + authorizationErrorCode.ToString() + " " + error.ToString());
        });
}
```

Here are the methods I'm using to generate a nonce:

```
public static string GenerateRandomString(int length)
{
    if (length <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Expected nonce to have positive length");
    }

    const string charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._";
    var cryptographicallySecureRandomNumberGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var result = string.Empty;
    var remainingLength = length;

    var randomNumberHolder = new byte[1];
    while (remainingLength > 0)
    {
        var randomNumbers = new List<int>(16);
        for (var randomNumberCount = 0; randomNumberCount < 16; randomNumberCount++)
        {
            cryptographicallySecureRandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomNumberHolder);
            randomNumbers.Add(randomNumberHolder[0]);
        }

        for (var randomNumberIndex = 0; randomNumberIndex < randomNumbers.Count; randomNumberIndex++)
        {
            if (remainingLength == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            var randomNumber = randomNumbers[randomNumberIndex];
            if (randomNumber < charset.Length)
            {
                result += charset[randomNumber];
                remainingLength--;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static string GenerateSHA256NonceFromRawNonce(string rawNonce)
{
    var sha = new SHA256Managed();
    var utf8RawNonce = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawNonce);
    var hash = sha.ComputeHash(utf8RawNonce);

    var result = string.Empty;
    for (var i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        result += hash[i].ToString("x2");
    }

    return result;
}
```

The error from xcode:

```
<<SignInWithApple>b__49_0>d:MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder:Start(TStateMachine&)
FirebaseModules:<SignInWithApple>b__49_0(ICredential)
AppleAuth.CallbackHandler:ExecutePendingCallbacks()

 Firebase.Auth.Credential
<<SignInWithApple>b__49_0>d:MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder:Start(TStateMachine&)
FirebaseModules:<SignInWithApple>b__49_0(ICredential)
AppleAuth.CallbackHandler:ExecutePendingCallbacks()

Failed to sign in with Firebase using Apple credentials: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to parse the ID Token.)
<<SignInWithApple>b__49_0>d:MoveNext()
System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:Run()
UnityEngine.WorkRequest:Invoke()
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:Exec()
```

I also have the auth object declared as public FirebaseAuth auth and the User object as public FirebaseUser User.

The platform I'm working on is macOS and I'm using Firebase SDK version 11.2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have been tackling with [Apple Sign](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/sign-in-with-apple-unity-plugin-152088) in for a while now and managed to implement it and it works just fine at the moment. I am using this [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/sign-in-with-apple-unity-plugin-152088#releases) available in unity asset store. It has a well written [document](https://github.com/lupidan/apple-signin-unity) which i highly suggest you to go through.

First thing i have noticed in your code is that you are using

> appleIdCredential.AuthorizationCode

which isn't the token you need to use. You need Identity Token instead.

> appleIdCredential.IdentityToken

Here is my implementation.

```
private void SignInWithApple()
    {
        var loginArgs = new AppleAuthLoginArgs(LoginOptions.IncludeEmail | LoginOptions.IncludeFullName);
    
        this.appleAuthManager.LoginWithAppleId(
            loginArgs,
            credential =>
            {
                // If a sign in with apple succeeds, we should have obtained the credential with the user id, name, and email, save it
                PlayerPrefs.SetString(Constants.AppleUserIdKey, credential.User);
            
                var appleIdCredential = credential as IAppleIDCredential;
                if (appleIdCredential != null)
                {
                    PlayerPrefs.SetString(Constants.AppleUserTokenKey, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(appleIdCredential.IdentityToken, 0, appleIdCredential.IdentityToken.Length));
                }
                
                this.AuthenticateWithFirebase();
            },
            error =>
            {
                var authorizationErrorCode = error.GetAuthorizationErrorCode();
                Debug.LogWarning("Sign in with Apple failed " + authorizationErrorCode.ToString() + " " + error.ToString());
                this.SetupLoginMenuForSignInWithApple();
            });
    }
```

After saving the token(s) needed, i call another method where i authenticate the user in firebase using the tokens i have grabbed from Apple Sign In. PS: This is how i generate my rawNonce. You should not need to download extra package to generate this.

> var rawNonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

```
public void AuthenticateWithFirebase()
    {
        SignInCompleteWith(ProviderType.Apple);

        var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

        var appleIdToken = PlayerPrefs.GetString(Constants.AppleUserTokenKey);
        var rawNonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        if (HasUser())
        {
            AuthenticationSuccessful(false);
            AddListenersToDatabase();
        }
        else
        {
            Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =
            Firebase.Auth.OAuthProvider.GetCredential("apple.com", appleIdToken, rawNonce, null);

            auth.SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {

                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Apple : SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                    SignOutUser();
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted) 
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Apple : SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                    SignOutUser();
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Apple Sign In : Task is completed successfully");
                    AuthenticationSuccessful(true);
                    AddListenersToDatabase();
                    SaveUserId();
                }                   
            });
        }
    }
```

Hope these will be helpful.

PS: There is no proper error handling in the code above, you should do better with your code :)