# Firebase Linking provider  SignIn not recognizing user

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in, oauth-provider

In the main login screen, users can select from different sign-in providers. Choosing one triggers the `signInWithCredential` function, which attempts to login and link the account if necessary.

However, Apple allows users to hide their email for privacy, preventing Firebase from recognizing the user and linking the account to other providers. Even using the `JWT sub` token for unique user identification doesn't solve the issue.

When the user logs out and re-enters using another provider, there's no way to retrieve the Apple user ID from the same database node, as Firebase assigns a new user ID. The original user ID gets stored in the database when a user first logs in.

```
/// Asynchronously signs in a user with a provided set of credentials.
/// - Parameters:
///   - credential: Authentication credentials to sign in the user.
///   - appleJWTToken: An optional JWT token for Apple sign-in (default is nil).
/// - Throws: An error of type `NSError` for any exceptions during the execution.
/// - Returns: No return value.

func signInWithCredential(credential: AuthCredential, appleJWTToken: String? = nil) async throws {
    do {
        // Attempt user authentication with provided credentials.
        let authResult = try await Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
        let currentUser = authResult.user

        // Verify the provider of the authentication credentials.
        if credential.provider == FirebaseProviders.Apple.rawValue, let appleJWTToken = appleJWTToken {
            // If the provider is Apple, store the JWT token in the database.
            try await storeJWTToken(appleJWTToken, forUser: currentUser.uid)
        } else if let pendingSignInData = pendingSignInData {
            // If a pending credential exists, link the account with it.
            try await linkFirebaseAccount(with: pendingSignInData.credential)
        } else {
            // Handle logins from other providers, and link Apple account if needed.
            let isAlreadyLinked = isLinkedWithApple(forUser: currentUser.uid)
            let appleJWT = try await retrieveAppleJWT(forUser: currentUser.uid)
            if let appleJWT = appleJWT, !isAlreadyLinked {
                // If Apple JWT exists and the user isn't already linked with Apple, create Apple credentials and link the account.
                let appleCredential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: FirebaseProviders.Apple.rawValue, idToken: appleJWT, rawNonce: nil)
                try await linkFirebaseAccount(with: appleCredential)
            }
            
            // Link other provider accounts, such as Google with Facebook.
            try await linkFirebaseAccount(with: credential)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // Handle errors related to account conflict or sign-in failure.
        if error.code == AuthErrorCode.accountExistsWithDifferentCredential.rawValue {
            let email = error.userInfo[AuthErrorUserInfoEmailKey] as! String
            let pendingCredential = error.userInfo[AuthErrorUserInfoUpdatedCredentialKey] as! AuthCredential
            guard let providers = try? await Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: email), let provider = providers.first else {
                throw SignInError.providerNotFound
            }
            pendingSignInData = PendingSignInData(email: email, credential: pendingCredential, method: provider)
            throw SignInError.signInConflict
        } else {
            throw SignInError.failedToSignIn(error)
        }
    }
}

    fileprivate func linkFirebaseAccount(with credential: AuthCredential) async throws {
            guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
                // Handle error.
                throw SignInError.failedToLinkAccount
            }
            
            do {
                try await currentUser.link(with: credential)
                pendingSignInData = nil  // Clear the pending data after successful linking.
            } catch {
                // Handle error.
                throw SignInError.failedToLinkAccount
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should be able to authenticate the user using apple sign in token. I am doing this in unity, regardless of the email address is hidden or not it links with the same account in my case. Are you getting any duplicate credential error?

Comment: No, it simply creates a new account each time the initial login is through a particular provider, such as Google, and then subsequently via Apple, or vice versa. The result remains the same in either case. Moreover, the token can't be found as it's stored under a different user ID than the one assigned during the initial Apple sign-in. @Berk

Comment: As far as i know, you get newly generated token every time a user signs in to any provider. I tried to sign in via Apple with hidden email option, then i removed the sign in from my account and re opt to sign in again but not hiding my email this time. It again linked my account to the same authenticated one in firebase. I will look into this and comeback if i find anything. Been spending quite some time on authentication and firebase. @David.C

Comment: It is all about the `uid` Apple's `uid` is not the same as Firebase's `uid`, if you want to support multiple login kinds you need to save the `uid` for the provider somewhere. Apple has a `uid` that does not change with an alias. Once the `uid` is created revoking does not make that id disappear.

Comment: Also, i wasn't able to save the UUid created by firebase after authentication. I am not sure why and i tested it many times, it somehow doesn't allow it to be saved. If you are deciding on whether that token exists or not it is probably the reason causing this case.

Comment: A lot of developer's don't take this into account, including large companies. Sign in with Apple is portrayed as this easy thing but there is a whole back end that needs to be implemented and accounted for so user's don't get locked out of your service permanently.

Comment: Here is a link to another question where i shared my answer if you want to check it out. Might be helpful might be not:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76746276/unity-apple-sign-in-and-firebase-auth/76749894#76749894

Comment: Both of your cases are intriguing. Could you please share some example code to illustrate your logic?

Comment: I don't have anything to share, look at the documentation there is a ton of it and it is all outlined there. Implementing Sign in with Apple with all the listeners needed is a long process that requires a server. One day I plan on creating a project and send it to Apple and/or the 2 companies (millions of users) I know are locking AppleID's out forever likely because they are missing the server side part.